# Why does my Custom User Control Property value not match the value that was set in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

### Background

---

As the title states, I have a Custom User Control.  I am using Silverlight 4, but I'm pretty sure this applies to WPF as well.  The goal is to create a control that will give options to DEVs to *show* only the parts of the control they want displayed on a particular page, along with *formatting*, *alignment*, *control alternate text*, and *orientation* properties.

The pieces that are to be shown are:

- `Country`
- `SubdivisionCategory` ( State, District, Outlying Territory )
- `SubdivisionCensusRegion` ( Northeast, South, Midwest, West )
- `SubdivisionCensusDivision` ( East North Central, East South Central, etc. )
- `Subdivision`

I am simply trying to access the values of the properties that are set when a DEV creates an instance of this control in XAML.  I have set up custom [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.95).aspx) objects for each property that I thought were for this purpose.

### Problem

---

My problem is that during `SetMargins()` all of the `this.ShowXxx` properties are equal to the value that was set in the `new PropertyMetadata(true)` portion of the [`DependencyProperty.Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.95).aspx) method signature.  Therefore, the margins are not being set correctly.

### Question

---

**How can I get the initial XAML value of the `this.ShowXxx` properties or any other property that I have set in XAML?**

### Code

---

Here's an example of the XAML markup:

```
<local:CountryAndSubdivisionFilter 
    x:Name="ReportSettingsCountryAndSubdivisionFilter"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    CountryFormat="Name"
    SubdivisionFormat="Name"
    ShowCountry="False"
    ShowSubdivisionCategory="False"
    ShowSubdivisionCensusRegion="False"
    ShowSubdivisionCensusDivision="True"
    ShowSubdivision="True"
    SubdivisionCensusDivisionText="Region"
    SubdivisionText="State"
    Margin="0,15,0,0" />
```

Here's an example of the `ShowCountry` property:

```
#region ShowCountry
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCountryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "ShowCountry",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CountryAndSubdivisionFilter),
    new PropertyMetadata(true)
);
public bool ShowCountry
{
    get
    {
        return (bool) GetValue(ShowCountryProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShowCountryProperty, value);

        this.CountryStackPanel.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.SetMargins();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Here is the `SetMargins()` method:

```
private void SetMargins()
{
    this.CountryStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    this.SubdivisionCategoryStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    this.SubdivisionCensusRegionStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    this.SubdivisionCensusDivisionStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    this.SubdivisionStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);

    var spList = new List<StackPanel>();

    if (this.ShowCountry)
        spList.Add(this.CountryStackPanel);

    if (this.ShowSubdivisionCategory)
        spList.Add(this.SubdivisionCategoryStackPanel);

    if (this.ShowSubdivisionCensusRegion)
        spList.Add(this.SubdivisionCensusRegionStackPanel);

    if (this.ShowSubdivisionCensusDivision)
        spList.Add(this.SubdivisionCensusDivisionStackPanel);

    if (this.ShowSubdivision)
        spList.Add(this.SubdivisionStackPanel);

    int spIndex = 1;
    foreach(var sp in spList)
    {
        var i = (spIndex < spList.Count) ? 15 : 0;
        var j = (spIndex == 1) ? 0 : 15;

        sp.Margin = (this.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                        ? new Thickness(0, 0, i, 0) 
                        : new Thickness(0, j, 0, 0);

        spIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

---

For my specific example above, what I had to do was create a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.95).aspx) called `OnShowCountryPropertyChanged` and from there I could set the property to the `NewValue`, which, initially, was the value that was assigned in XAML.

To wire this callback up, I simply had to update the [`PropertyMetadata Constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557330(v=vs.95).aspx) of my [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) adding to the default value, a reference to my callback.

**Old Signature:** `new PropertyMetadata(true)`

**New Signature:** `new PropertyMetadata(true, OnShowCountryPropertyChanged)`

Once I did those two things, the XAML value was being used when the getter for the property was accessed in my `SetMargins()` method.

### Update Code

---

```
#region ShowCountry
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCountryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "ShowCountry",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CountryAndSubdivisionFilter),
    new PropertyMetadata(true, OnShowCountryPropertyChanged)
);
public bool ShowCountry
{
    get
    {
        return (bool) GetValue(ShowCountryProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShowCountryProperty, value);

        this.CountryStackPanel.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.SetMargins();
    }
}
private static void OnShowCountryPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = d as CountryAndSubdivisionFilter;
    ctrl.ShowCountry = (bool) e.NewValue;
}
#endregion
```